# Detect own application HTTP traffic

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to add a counter to my winforms application that counts how many MB of data I communicated with the server. The server is a web service but I only need to know how many (mega)bytes of data the client is uploading/downloading with the server.

The counter should be implemented in my app so I do not rely on a third party app.

Comment: You can keep your uploading and download code in a central location and log there.

Comment: agree, but my app sends out JSON data obtained after serializing some objects. I don't really want to calculate each object size before transmitting the data.